# Finding Connection Forms on a surface

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

I'm trying to understand connection forms on Riemannian Manifolds and I am kind of confused by this example that I found in a paper I am reading

[image]

[image]

I am pretty sure I understand how $w_1,w_2$ were found, but $w_{12}$ is the connection form and I've been searching through quite a few sources and I am just not understanding how they find it. From my readings, I found the connection form is found by calculating $w_{12}(v) = \nabla_v e_1 \cdot e_2$ where $v$ is an element in the tangent space, so a vector field. And $\nabla_v e_1= \frac{d}{dt}e_1(p+tv)(0)$ for a point $p$ on our manifold, but then I am confused are we evaluating a vector field $e_1$ in terms of another vector field, similar to the Lie bracket for example? Then with respect to the dot product, we use the Riemannian metric defined by $w_1$ and $w_2$ to find it I think. But I am just kind of confused about this whole thing, I am fairly new to Riemannian Geometry and this idea of a connection form really confuses me. If somebody could help me with this example or any other example that would be great, I am having a lot of difficulties understanding this but it seems like such a simple concept...

Comment: Quick suggestion. Download my (free) differential geometry notes, linked in my profile, and read through section 3 of chapter 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using some rather compact notation, we have that if $\mathfrak{e}=\mathfrak{v}R_\phi$, then $$\omega = R_{-\phi}\theta R_\phi + R_{-\phi} {\rm d}(R_\phi),$$because this is the general transformation law for local connection $1$-forms relative to two different frames, in terms of the change-of-basis matrix. Now, this becomes $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \omega_{12} \\ -\omega_{12} & 0\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi & \sin\phi \\ -\sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \theta_{12} \\ -\theta_{12} & 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi & -\sin\phi \\ \sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}+ \begin{pmatrix} \cos\phi & \sin\phi \\ -\sin\phi & \cos\phi\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} -\sin\phi & -\cos\phi \\ \cos\phi & -\sin\phi\end{pmatrix}\,{\rm d}\phi. $$Looking only at the $(1,2)$-entry, the desired formula follows after applying $\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi=1$.

---

Proof of transformation law. If $(M,\nabla)$ is any affine manifold (i.e., $M$ is equipped with an arbitrary affine connection $\nabla$; it may have torsion, $M$ doesn't need to have a metric, we're doing it freestyle), and $\mathfrak{e}$ and $\mathfrak{v}$ are local frames with connection $1$-form matrices $\theta$ and $\omega$, and related via $\mathfrak{e} = \mathfrak{v}A$ for some non-singular matrix of functions $A$, we'll show that $$\theta = A^{-1}\omega A + A^{-1}{\rm d}A.$$

Namely, our assumptions fully written are that $$e_j = \sum_i a^i_{\,j}v_i,\quad \nabla e_j = \sum_i\theta^i_{\,j}\otimes e_i,\quad \nabla v_j = \sum_i \omega^i_{\,j}\otimes v_i.$$We'll write the latter two simply as $$\nabla\mathfrak{e} = \mathfrak{e}\theta\quad\mbox{and}\quad \nabla\mathfrak{v} = \mathfrak{v}\omega.$$Thus, we compute $$\mathfrak{v}A\theta = \mathfrak{e}\theta = \nabla\mathfrak{e} = \nabla(\mathfrak{v}A) = (\nabla\mathfrak{v})A+\mathfrak{v}\,{\rm d}A = \mathfrak{v}\omega A +\mathfrak{v}\,{\rm d}A = \mathfrak{v}(\omega A + {\rm d}A), $$so linear independence of $\mathfrak{v}$ gives $$A\theta = \omega A + {\rm d}A \implies \theta = A^{-1}\omega A + A^{-1}\,{\rm d}A.$$Same proof gives same transformation law for connection $1$-forms in an arbitrary vector bundle with connection, and two local trivializations.

---

You can try to read my [short notes on Cartan computations](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/cartan_formalism.pdf), pages 11 through 14 of my [notes on principal bundles](https://www.asc.ohio-state.edu/terekcouto.1/texts/principal.pdf), and the [book by Loring Tu (Amazon link)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B073H8B78M).